# Почему ls не показывает цвета при запуске из скрипта

Tags: bash, unix

Цвета не показываются, если запустить `ls` из скрипта:

```
#!/bin/sh
ls
```

При обычном запуске цвета показываются.

Comment: Почему был удалён подобный вопрос от @alexander barakin?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Если ответ нашёлся, то он обычно публикуется как ответ, а не удаляется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При обычном запуске `ls` является alias`ом у меня:

```
$ type ls
alias ls='ls --color=tty'
```

При запуске из скрипта используется не alias, а просто `/bin/ls` исполняемый файл, который не показывает цвета в моём окружении:

```
$ ls       # есть цвета
$ /bin/ls  # нет цветов
```

В скрипте:

```
#!/bin/sh
ls              # нет цветов
ls --color=tty  # есть цвета
```

Скрипт запускается как:

```
$ ./ls-colors
```